# Has there been a reaction from the West's Left to Ukraine's suspending of some "socialist" political parties (for alleged ties to Russia)?

Tags: russian-federation, parties, ukraine, socialism, western-world

A few days ago [Ukrainian government suspended 11 political parties with links to Russia](https://www.businessinsider.com/zelesnkyy-suspends-ukrainian-opposition-parties-with-ties-to-russia-2022-3?r=US&IR=T)(original order [here](https://www.president.gov.ua/documents/1532022-41765)), specifically:
*[Opposition Platform - For Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_Platform_%E2%80%94_For_Life), [Shariy Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_of_Shariy), [Nashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashi_(political_party)), [Opposition Bloc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_Bloc), **Left Opposition**, **[Union of Left Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_of_Leftists)**, State, **[Progressive Socialist Party of Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Socialist_Party_of_Ukraine)**, **[Socialist Party of Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_Party_of_Ukraine)**, **Socialists Party**, and Volodymyr Saldo Bloc* (emphasis mine).

Socialist and left-wing parties in Ukraine, for obvious historical reasons, have stronger ties to Russia. What interests me is whether any Western socialists or pro-socialist politicians issued clarifying statements in connection to this?

*Remarks*

- I am mostly interested in Bernie Sanders and the Squad in the US, as well as the Socialist and Communist candidates in the nearing French presidential election.

Comment: To what extent are these actually left-wing parties as per a "Western" understanding of left-wing? For example, the Wikipedia article on the Progressive Socialist Party of Ukraine states (without providing details) that the party uses left-wing rethoric, but actually espouses conservative positions.

Comment: @Arno I remarked on the *historical reasons* - *conservative* in post-Soviet space is usually everything related to the USSR, which is socialist in economic sphere, but rather non-liberal in terms of individual freedoms.

Comment: Keep in mind there is socialist and there is "socialist". Many political groups pretend to be socialist but are really just fascist (or something else) in socialist's clothing.

Comment: @user253751 True. Also *socialism* is often used as a colloquial term, referring really to a *social democracy*, which is usually practiced by capitalist societies, like those in western Europe.

Comment: So 5 out of 11 banned were Socialist? Seems about half. Can't see an anti-left bias there. The Kremlin is suspected of creating spoiler parties of all colors, by the way. Inside and outside Russia. The BBC seems correct that out of those 11 "Opposition Platform - For Life" is the largest, and it's not a Socialist one, at least not by name.

Comment: I'm not even sure if any of the ones with "Socialist" in their name was in Parliament (Rada). A quick google search on their name is either negative or inconclusive.

Comment: @Fizz I am not claiming any bias here - just asking whether there were any statements in this relation. On the nature of *socialism* in post-Soviet space, see me above comments.

Answer (score 3):

Frame shift:  is it unusual for democracies to ban political parties in wartime, *if those parties have specific ties to enemy nations*?  **So why do left-aligned parties in the West really have to give an opinion?**

Also, I question the notion that Western *Socialist*, not *Communist* parties have significant affiliations with Russia now.  Or indeed that they did in Soviet times.

Currently, a lot of Putin affiliation seems to be more on the right end of things, for example [Le Pen's campaign getting a loan](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/a-russian-bank-gave-marine-le-pens-party-a-loan-then-weird-things-began-happening/2018/12/27/960c7906-d320-11e8-a275-81c671a50422_story.html).

In fact, [Le Pen is not the only hard right party with this image problem](https://www.economist.com/europe/2022/03/21/the-invasion-of-ukraine-is-making-life-difficult-for-right-wing-populists) (that's an Economist article, so behind a paywall, but the cringe-y picture of Italy's Salvini, in the dark jacket, is viewable without logging in).

> On a visit to the Polish border town of Przemysl on March 8th he was humiliated by the mayor, who presented him with a t-shirt featuring Mr Putin—similar to one Mr Salvini wore smilingly in a photo on Red Square in 2014 (see picture: Mr Salvini is on the right)

And let's not even mention our dear Tucker Carlson.  I am no fan of Sanders.  Or "The Squad", whose main contribution seems to consist of feeding oxygen to "radical left" hysteria by Trump supporters. But this question is out of the blue and skirts close to "aim to discredit".

Comment: Funnily enough, there is speculation that "Socialist" niche parties may actually have links to Belorussian KGB and not to Russia.

Comment: @alamar Sanders and mainstream French socialist candidates wouldn't be in that niche however, so again, not a very useful comment, esp without sources.  No idea what a looney like Jean-Luc Melenchon is up to however, nor do I aim to answer about his type though.

Comment: I'm talking about Ukrainian and other post-Soviet states' parties and not Sanders.

Comment: If so, please make it more clear what exactly you do mean.  Accusing any kind of sane, normal, political parties of ties to the Belarus KGB is a pretty harsh claim.

Comment: Why? A lot of parties have ties to special services of neighbouring countries. It's more of an error to discount this. I have to disclose I don't have sources, but it was noted that socialist movements in Russia have unnatural affinity for Belarus. I theorize the same may be true for Ukraine. This is more plausible than their link to Russia, which again would need to be proven.

Comment: Oh, I see, Socialist Ukrainian parties -> Belarus, rather than Western Socialist parties -> Belarus.  I have no opinion, but it's also not that relevant to my line of answer, which is that the OP's question doesn't seem to have a lot of solid ground for being asked.  Also "need to be proven" is easy to say, from within a country **not** at war.  Ukraine may very well need to clean up its act, on all sorts of levels, once it gets past this crisis.  Esp if it wants to join the EU.  But for now it doesn't seem totally unreasonable to temp-ban parties that can reasonably be claimed to be proRussia

Comment: Seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: It is not uncommon, but that is quite different from suggesting that it a good idea. Yes, democracies have a long history of restrictions on parties (and whole groups of people) accused of sympathies toward their enemies. But this is fundamentally against the nature of liberal democracy: the freedom to disagree with your government's stance even during a war.

Comment: As I mentioned above, this is the reasoning that Cuba uses to ban all opposition parties: that they have ties to the United States. It doesn't sound any better when the Ukrainian government does it. Unless the party is directly being controlled by Russia, which may the case with some, it just ends up amounting to suppression of disagreement. Most of these pro-Russian parties don't even support Putin's invasion (at least publicly). The same thing with Zelenskiy's idea to combine all TV channels to have "a unified message" (read: make sure that his perspective is the only one).

Comment: @Obie2.0 I'll be more inclined to chime in on how Ukraine should run its political system once they are not at war anymore.  Not that I necessarily disagree with what you say but their circumstances are not normal circumstances.  And the Cuba analogy isn't all that strong:  Cuba isn't at war with the US, neither is Iran, so both are indeed faulty for suppressing dissent.  Western wartime political regimes are rarely a poster children for democracy and the free exchange of ideas.  At least during a **real** war, rather than say the Vietnam War or Iraq.  So for now we'll agree to disagree.

Comment: @RogerVadim if you say so.  But what I am doing is answering by reframing this question for what it is:  a weak question.  On the other hand, this site has been closing tons of questions and answers whenever they do not portray Ukraine in an entirely positive light.  Ukraine was pretty high on the corruption list before this (lower than Russia though).  It will not be free of problems after this is over either.  Asking what Western left parties, **in particular**, think of these, **wartime**, bans seems totally gratuitous, to me and can be answered as such, no need to close.  I DVd, didnt VTC

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica It´s arguable if Ukraine is les corupt then Russia and this is not my opinion, but of Gordon a ukrainian journalist and suporter of Zelenski.

Comment: @Obie2.0 it's more than just an accusation.  The [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Medvedchuk) of the block has personal family ties to Putin.  And his party has connections to the violent pro-Russian separatists in the East of Ukraine.  He himself has been [sanctioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Medvedchuk#Alleged_involvement_in_the_2014_separatist_movements_and_Russo-Ukrainian_War) by the United States for his involvement in Russia's annexation of Crimea.

Comment: @Obie2.0: And the most significant (nominally) left-wing party banned was the SPU. But apparently it had become a shell of its former self. They last had seats in the Rada in 2006. The candidate (Illia Kyva) they had put for presidency in 2019 had already fled to Russia, before the invasion. And he also had joined "Opposition Platform — For Life" in the meantime, although he was even expelled from that after he fled.